# How to animate label Text using ZCAnimatedLabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

ZCAnimatedLabel extends UIView because of which UILabel class can not be repointed to ZCAnimatedLabel. What is the correct way to animate label text using ZCAnimatedLabel?

Comment: https://github.com/overboming/ZCAnimatedLabel for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have questions about CocoaPods Libraries than first checkout there git repo to understand how to use it.
[ZCAnimatedLabel](https://github.com/overboming/ZCAnimatedLabel)

Try this :

```
ZCAnimatedLabel *label;
label.animationDuration = 1;
label.animationDelay = 1;
label.text = @"AnimateLabel";
// add animation type
object_setClass(label, [ZCAnimatedLabel class]);
// start Animation
[label startAppearAnimation];
```

To stop animation:

```
[self.label startDisappearAnimation];
```

Different type of animations you can add to label:

```
//Throw
object_setClass(label, [ZCThrownLabel class]);
//Shapeshift
object_setClass(label, [ZCShapeshiftLabel class]);
//Default
object_setClass(label, [ZCAnimatedLabel class]);
//Duang
object_setClass(label, [ZCDuangLabel class]);
//Fall
object_setClass(label, [ZCFallLabel class]);
//Alpha
object_setClass(label, [ZCTransparencyLabel class]);
//Flyin
object_setClass(label, [ZCFlyinLabel class]);
//Blur
object_setClass(label, [ZCFocusLabel class]);
//Reveal
object_setClass(label, [ZCRevealLabel class]);
//Spin
object_setClass(label, [ZCSpinLabel class]);
label.layerBased = YES;
//Dash
object_setClass(label, [ZCDashLabel class]);
label.layerBased = YES;
```

Comment: If you have any question about ZCAnimatedLabel you can comment here.